# Reconstruct Veritasium's plots from one the videos

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

Inspired by one of Veritasium Youtube video where he explained chaotic bifurcation map (logistic map). the mathematical equation is simply: `X[i+1]=R*X[i](1-X[i])`

the first graph he plots: this `X[i]` values (y-axis values, in the range of 0 to 1) versus iteration time `i` (x-axis values, number of calculation) with a certain value of R (say, R_init=2, and I wanted to incorporate a Slider in my code for changing the value of R)

the second graph (the bifurcation graph) he plots: the value R (x-axis values) versus equilibrium population of X[i], that is: the number of X[i] values that it oscillates between (depending on the R value, after certain/many iteration i, X[i] can oscillate between finite numbers and also infinite numbers -- chaos!)

Eventually, in the code, I want two side by side subplot, left one is the "first graph" with the Slider for those two variables, right side is the "second graph".
Below I pasted the my code for a starter, where I only try to achieve plotting "first graph" with a Slider for R and initial value of X[0] (but, of course, it failed to show anything so far..)
I'd appreciate if anyone can help me finishing up this project, or giving me some advice on my problematic code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

R = 1.5
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1)
k_init = 0.4       # initial y value

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.axes([0.125, 0.15, 0.775, 0.80])

myplot, = plt.plot(0, 0, c="royalblue")     # not really ploting anything first
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.ylim(0, 1)

# create slider panel & values sets
slider_r = plt.axes([0.125, 0.03, 0.775, 0.03])
slider_k = plt.axes([0.125, 0.07, 0.775, 0.03])
r_slider = Slider(slider_r, "R", 1, 20, valinit=R, valstep=0.1)
k_slider = Slider(slider_k, "k_init", 0, 1, valinit=k_init, valstep=0.05)

k = []     # y-values starts with List items
def update(*args):
    k.append(k_init)
    for i in np.arange(1,100,1):
        k_new = R*(k[i-1])*(1-(k[i-1]))    
        k.append(k_new)
    y = np.array(k)
    myplot.set_xdata(x)
    myplot.set_ydata(y)

r_slider.on_changed(update)
k_slider.on_changed(update)

update()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please, start with creating still images and make that work well, and only then add sliders etc. If you combine too many unknowns, it is very hard to get a grasp of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

- replace `x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1)` by `x = np.arange(100)`
- remove `k = []`
- add `k0, R = k_slider.val, r_slider.val` at the beginning of `update` function
- replace `k.append(k_init)` by `k = [k0]`

### Long answer

#### 1. Get a simulation that runs (without animation)

First, let's try to obtain a working plot without sliders. Here are some tips and some things to fix:

- `x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1)` only contains one element, while `y` will contain 100 values!
- As the final size of `y` is already known, initialize it as an empty array, instead of adding items to the list `k`. This will make the code more readable and faster.
- Use variables to store constant values such as the number of epochs.
- In the description of the problem you use the variable `x` whereas in the implementation it is `y` ans `k`: Define notations that make sense, and stick to them.
- It is rather confusing to define such similar names as `r_slider` and `slider_r` , especially since these two variables store completely different objects.

```py
## define constants
R = 2.6
X0 = 0.5  # initial value
N = 75  # number of epochs

## logistic map iterates
def get_logistic_map(x0, R, N):
    x = np.empty(N)
    x[0] = x0
    for i in range(1, N):
        x[i] = R * x[i-1] * (1 - x[i-1])
    return x

x = get_logistic_map(X0, R, N)

## plot
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
plt.plot(x, 'o-', c="royalblue", ms=2)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.margins(x=.01)
plt.grid(c="lightgray")
plt.xlabel(r"$n$")
plt.ylabel(r"$x_n$")
plt.show()
```

#### 2. Let's bring in interaction with sliders

In function `update`:

- You should update the data displayed using the new values of the sliders. Usually when a slider is updated, it gives its new value as an argument to the callback function (here `update` function). Since here two sliders are linked to the same update function, you cannot use this input parameter. However you can access these values using attribute `val` of each slider. (And since such callback functions require a parameter, you use an `*args` appropriately ;).
- I'm not sure if it is intentional or not, but `k` is a global list. So each time `update` is called 100 **new** values are added.

```py
## Prepare figure layout
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
ax = plt.axes([0.125, 0.15, 0.775, 0.80])
line, = plt.plot(range(N), np.zeros(N), 'o-', c="royalblue", ms=2)
# set the layout of the main axes before defining the axes of the sliders
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlim(0, N-1)

## Create sliders
ax_slider_x0 = plt.axes([0.125, 0.03, 0.775, 0.03])
ax_slider_r = plt.axes([0.125, 0.07, 0.775, 0.03])

slider_x0 = Slider(ax_slider_x0, r"$x_0$", 0, 1, valinit=X0)
slider_r = Slider(ax_slider_r, r"$R$", 0, 4, valinit=R)
# plt.sca(ax) # uncomment to set the main axes as the current one

def update(*args):
    x0_val, r_val = slider_x0.val, slider_r.val
    x = get_logistic_map(x0_val, r_val, N)
    line.set_ydata(x)
    # Set the title on the main axes (plt.title would have added a
    # title on the current axes (by default the last one to be defined)
    ax.set_title(rf"Logistic map with $R$={r_val:.3f} and $x_0={x0_val:.3f}$")

slider_x0.on_changed(update)
slider_r.on_changed(update)

update() # initialize the plot
plt.show()
```

> **A personal tip –** To debug a callback function with sliders, it is tempting to scatter some `print`. But as this turns out to be fruitless, you can instead display the debugging text inside the title of the plot!

[image: results]

#### 3. What's next?

Now the first plot is interactive. For the bifurcation graph, I don't see the interactivity that could be added.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Very thorough and informative, I learn a lot!! Only wondering, what is the syntax of `r"$x_0$"` I can't find any documents explaining this formatting of axis label...also in the interactive graph, you used `plt.axes` to plot instead of `plt.plot` in the static graph case, then if I want to add some padding on the left of X-axis, when I use `plt.axes(xmargin=.01)` I don't know why the graph turned little messy/haywire. Finally, yeah, the bifurcation graph should not have any slider, but currently I just purely have no clue of how to plotting this...lol

Comment: Actually math formulas can be rendered in matplotlib using TeX syntax (between the $).

Comment: In the interactive graph, `plt.axes` is not used to plot the data but to add an axes with custom dimension to the current figure. What is to be understood here is that the figure is composed of 3 axes (1 for the main graph and 2 for the sliders). When using `plt.something`, the action is performed on the active axes, i.e. the last one to have been defined. So attention should be paid on the location of `plt.something`. As an more flexible alternative, store the axes in a variable, say `ax`, and then either make it active via `plt.sca(ax)` or use `ax.something` or `ax.set_something`.

Comment: This is so cool! TeX makes the title interactive as well!
In addition, do you have some clue on the bifurcation plot? From the interactive graph, it seems after 70 iteration/epoch, the values starts to bouncing between either finite number of values or many values(chaos when R >4) Maybe I can make a empty list to append those emergent values under each R case?

Comment: Oh, correction, it's the f-string making the title interactive here :P

Comment: It seems like R should be between 0 and 4 (beyond 4, x can grow above 1) with 3 the value from which chaos appears. For the bifurcation plot I would go this way: For each value of R, compute the logistic values until epochs N, and plot (R, xi) where xi are the (100) last values. If you struggle with it, maybe it is worth opening a new question. Have fun!

Comment: Sliders in matplotlib are often tedious to use. Take a look at ipywidgets to bring in interaction inside a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I started a new question, where I'm really confused that the code failed if using np.unique() function