# Baffled by numpy.unique()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

As an extension to my previous [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692421/reconstruct-veritasiums-plots-from-one-the-videos), where the equation `X[i+1]=R*X[i](1-X[i])` is used to demonstrate a chaotic system (depending on R). Now I'm trying to construct the bifurcation graph.

About the code, I defined the function to do the actual calculations, and extracting the last 100 calculated values (to ensure the equilibrium reached), in order to plot out the bifurcated R vs x[i], I'm appending each R value to a empty X-data list, and multiple (aka, the returned 100 values) x[i] to a Y-data list (so it is actually a nested list...)

The thing is, depending on the R value, x[i] can be either single value (after equilibrium reached) or multiple values. So I was thinking to "purify" the nested Y-data list by numpy.unique() to remove all the replicated values.

Weirdly, when I don't make the extra "purification" step, the code actually works.

But when I put `x = np.unique(logistic_calc(R,N))` it throws me a error says `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Below is the code that works...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R = 0.2
N = 10_000
x0 = 0.5

def logistic_calc(R,N):
    x = np.empty(N)
    x[0] = x0
    for i in range(1, N):
        x[i] = R* x[i-1] * (1 - x[i-1])
    return x[-100:]

x_lst = [] 
y_lst = []
for r in np.linspace(0.1,4,100):
    R = r 
    x = logistic_calc(R,N)
    x_lst.append(r)
    y_lst.append(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
plt.plot(x_lst, y_lst, ls='', marker='.',ms='0.5', c="royalblue")
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.grid(c="lightgray")
plt.xlabel(r"$r$")
plt.ylabel(r"$x_n$")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), paragraph "Plotting multiple sets of data":

> "If x and/or y are 2D arrays a separate data set will be drawn for every column. If both x and y are 2D, they must have the same shape. If only one of them is 2D with shape (N, m) the other must have length N and will be used for every data set m."

It is not explicitly written that all sublists must have the same length. But it only refers to 2D arrays and not ragged nested sequences. To understand the behavior of `plt.plot`, just imagine that `x` and `y` will be cast into numpy arrays. In your second case, since `y_lst` contains lists with different lengths, this conversion cannot be made.

So I would go for something like this:

```py
plt.figure(figize=(7, 4))
for r in np.linspace(1, 4, 100):
    x = np.unique(logistic_calc(r, N))
    plt.plot([r], [x], '.', ms=.5, c="royalblue")  # a little bit tricky!
    # OR
    # plt.plot([r] * len(x), x, '.', ms=.5, c="royalblue")

...
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. Now I sorta understand the problem. Essentially `plt.plot` are drawing multiple sets when either x-data or y-data is more than 1 dimension, therefore a dimension-matching issue needs attention. Then I'm wondering, in general, when one has multiple y-data corresponds to one x-data, can `plt.scatter` be a solution? Or it basically follows the same idea as `plt.plot` ...?

Comment: For example `plt.plot(x=[0, 1, 2, 3], y=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]` will work since `len(x) == len(y)` and amounts to creating the following 3 plots`plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7, 10])`, `plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 8, 11])` and `plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 9, 12])`. This is why all sublists must have the same number of elements.
So in the 1st case when `x_lst` is a simple list of length `nR` and `y_lst` contains `nR` lists of length `m`, `plt.plot(x_lst, y_lst)`  should be thought ""horizontally"" as "Draw me the `m` lines `(x_lst, y_lst[i])`".

Comment: And `plt.scatter` strictly requires that `x` and `y` to be the same size.
Note that `plt.scatter` handle each point as an individual object, while `plt.plot` with argument `o` will treat them as single line. Hence when you want all points to have the same appearance, always use `plt.plot`.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your example with `np.unique`, I get ...

```
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    plt.plot(x_lst, y_lst, ls='', marker='.',ms='0.5', c="royalblue")

... more stack trace

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So the error is clearly happening at line ...

```py
plt.plot(x_lst, y_lst, ls='', marker='.',ms='0.5', c="royalblue")
```

because the shapes of `x_lst` and `y_lst` no longer match up when you use `np.unique`.

You can get the code to work by looping over each each index of `x_lst` and `y_lst` and plotting them separately ...

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R = 0.2
N = 10_000
x0 = 0.5

def logistic_calc(R,N):
    x = np.empty(N)
    x[0] = x0
    for i in range(1, N):
        x[i] = R* x[i-1] * (1 - x[i-1])
    return x[-100:]

x_lst = [] 
y_lst = []
for r in np.linspace(0.1,4,100):
    R = r 
    x = logistic_calc(R,N)
    x = x.reshape(100)
    x_lst.append(r)
    y_lst.append(np.unique(x.round(decimals=4)))

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
for x, y in zip(x_lst, y_lst):
    plt.plot([x]*len(y), y, ls='', marker='.',ms='0.5', c="royalblue")
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.grid(c="lightgray")
plt.xlabel(r"$r$")
plt.ylabel(r"$x_n$")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code modification. My confusion was, before using `np.unique(x)` eventually after `for r in np.linspace(0.1,4,100)` loop appending, y_lst is a list of 100 items, where each item is a list consists of 100 float numbers, and x_lst is simply a list of 100 float numbers, and under this situation, `plt.plot(x_lst, y_lst)` works fine. But why, when I "purify" the y_lst (still a list of 100 items, yet each item may be a list consist of single or multiple float numbers) and then the `plt.plot` doesn't work?

Comment: It's as nonin states, though you're feeding it lists that have the same length, `plt.plot` is expecting that each list is transformable into a simple `np.ndarray`. Your `y` list is _ragged_, and so it can't be teased into a 1D or 2D `ndarray` of primitive numeric types (int, float, etc.). At most you can build an `ndarray` of `object` type from `y`, but that won't work here.

Comment: I see! Thanks for all the kind help!